# Unique Indexes with Oracle partitioned tables

Tags: oracle, indexing, oracle11g

I have a table `Customer_Chronics` in Oracle 11g.
 The table has three key columns as shown below :

- branch_code
- customer_id
- period

I have partitioned by table by list of `branch_code`, and now I'm having dilemma.  Which is better:

1. Create unique index indexNumberOne on Customer_Chronics (PERIOD, CUSTOMER_ID);
2. Create unique index indexNumberTwo on Customer_Chronics (branch_code, PERIOD, CUSTOMER_ID);

The actual data must be unique by `period, customer_id`. If I put a unique index only on these two columns Oracle will check all partitions on the table when inserting new records?

Answer (score 3):

The only way to enforce uniqueness is with a unique constraint on the columns of interest.  So that's your first option.  The database will check all values across all partitions it this case.  But as it's a unique index that shouldn't take too long no matter how big the table gets (if that's your concern).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, If you put unique index on that two columns only, Oracle will create a global index and will check all partitions. This is one of challenges I face sometime because we prefer local indexs for big tables (small tables should be OK).